# Why does my profile show an account on Judaism SE?

Tags: support, bug

I do not have any account on Judaism SE. What do I need to remove that from my profile?

Comment: A priest.${}{}$

Comment: @Gerry: If one is born into Judaism, one can never leave it. No matter what you'll do - you remain Jewish. So even a priest is not going to do much good for that...

Comment: @Asaf, well, you can get thrown out (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza#Expulsion_from_the_Jewish_community). So maybe OP needs a rabbi.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, but he remained Jewish until he died and turned into a lifeless corpse of a person that was Jewish.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: not to turn this into a discussion on Who Is A Jew, but Spinoza was excommunicated - he was not considered Jewish after that by his contemporaries (even though Huygens did refer to him as the Jew Spinoza).  Those who are on the more, ummm, severe (?) side of orthodoxy are still annoyed when people speak of Spinoza as a Jew.  (I totally consider him Jewish - nobody gets excommunicated like that anymore.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the account shows that you have earned the "citizen patrol" badge for "flagging your first post". It also says that the last time you logged on was Feb 10 at 5:36. Your activity page also shows that you left two comments on the site the same day you were awarded the badge (January $21^{st}$) and no other activity. Are you sure you do these things and then forget about it? You can ask the moderators of a site to delete your account on that site if you wish. Other than talking to the moderators, I don't think that there's much you can do.

Comment: Accounts can be deleted either from an individual site, or network-wide, this is up to the user. Of course, a site's mod can only delete accounts from that site. (SE would not want the setup in which a mod from EL&U can delete [Jon Skeet](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/11452/jon-skeet) from the whole network.)

Comment: @75064 This is what I suspected thank you for confirming! I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think there is some sort of bug in the system as I do not have any activity on Judaism. Maybe, some other user's account has been associated with me due to an error. Accordingly, I am tagging my question as a bug.

Comment: @response, so [this isn't you](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2302/response?tab=activity)? Alright... then at the very least somebody put in your e-mail address when registering for that site. To get rid of your account, go [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion).